# Error: "product distribution file not verified", trying to update mac to el capitan

Tags: macos, osx-elcapitan

When I click the "Free Upgrade" button in apple store, an error message shows up.
The message says "The product distribution file could not be verified. It may be damaged or was not signed."

I googled about it and tried following things.

1. reboot mac.
2. try another network.
3. clean the $TMPDIR/../C/ directory
4. rename the /Library/Caches directory
5. download the pkg file and change hosts file, setup a webserver on localhost. according to this [article](https://7labs.heypub.com/tips-tricks/el-capitan-direct-download.html)

None of them works for me.

Comment: Sadly, I have to download a dmg installing file to update to El Capitan.